# JavaScript: how to Prevent Double button click or disable the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a webpage where multiple user information details is there.so when i click on the complete (here complete button is there beside every user details) button it should do some task(eg. I'm sending mail here) and disable the button after i redirected to same page again.
How do I do it?
Any possible suggestion?

[ It's a blade template as i'm making laravel web application]

A demo of my webpage:

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <title> User Details </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script> 

    </head>
    <body>


<div class="container">
<h3> Student Details </h3>
      <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered"  id="example">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Serial No</td>
            <td>Student Name</td>
            <td>Stdunet Email</td>
            <td>Course Name</td>  
            <td>Phone Number</td>
          <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <?php $i=1; ?>
        @foreach($user as $row)
        @if($row->courses()->first())
          <tr>
            <td>{{$i}}</td>
            <td>{{$row->name }}</td>
            <td>{{$row->email}}</td>
           <td>{{$row->courses()->first()->name}} </td>
            <td>{{$row->phone}}</td>
           <td>

               <a href="{{route('sendMail',$row->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning">Complete</a>                                        

            </td>
          </tr>
          <?php $i++; ?>
          @endif


        @endforeach
        </tbody>


      </table>

    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery's `.one()` method.

```js
// prevent anchor to click 
$(document).ready(function() {
  var clickCtr = 0;  
  $("a.btn").click( function() {
    if(clickCtr > 0) {
      return false; 
    }
    clickCtr++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://www.google.co.in" target="_blank" class="btn btn-warning">Complete</a>
```

Comment: See the problem is with your solution is when i click in the first time it's showing clicked and do the task but when i click again it's again do the task but i don't want to do that!
it should either disable the button or preventing from further click.
here to mention I have list of same button in same page as you can see.

Comment: @x69 Ok updated code accordingly, see working demo here - https://jsfiddle.net/pradeep1991singh/wzj5o3kz/1/

Answer (score 0):

So there is couple ways to handle your issue.

A simple one from the client side would be to use jQuery (since your importing it in your HTML) to temporarily disable the button.

Here is an exemple:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     clicked = false;
     $(".btn").on('click', function (event) {  
           if (!clicked) {
             clicked = true;
             $(".text").text("Clicked!");
             setTimeout(function(){ 
               clicked = false;
               $(".text").text("");
             }, 2000);
           } else {
              $(".text").text("Already clicked!");
           }
     });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-warning">Complete</button>
<text class="text"></text>
```